# Python Pandas - Update column values based on two lists

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have a table like this

| Company_Name | Product |
| --- | --- |
| A | Apple |
| B | Orange |
| C | Pear |
| D | Lemon |

Given two lists
list1 = ['Pear', 'Lemon', 'Apple', 'Orange']
list2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]

How to replace Product name with the numerical values? The output should look like this -

| Company_Name | Product |
| --- | --- |
| A | 3 |
| B | 4 |
| C | 1 |
| D | 2 |

Comment: Use your lists to make a dictionary, and then map your column: `mapper = dict(zip(list1,list2))` and then `df.prod = [mapper[val] for val in df.prod]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
table["Product"] = table["Product"].apply(lambda p: list2[list1.index(p)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing

```
mapper = dict(zip(list1,list2))
df['prod'] = df['prod'].map(mapper)
```